# Customizing the special character feature associated with ios devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, keyboard, customization

Quick question.  After reading through many related posts I haven't been able to find an answer.

I will be creating a "simple" text editing app in which I will need the special characters (that you have to hold the key down to access) customized.  For example, the key for the number 5.  If I press it without holding, it will type "5".  My question is would it be possible to create a special character (perhaps a 5 within the shape of a diamond) that is accessible only when I press and hold the 5 key?

Any input would be absolutely appreciated!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Think you can't do that with system provided keyboard You have to create your own custom keyboard and use [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to identify long press and change the value accordingly.